Keep system audio toggle button on by default while screen recording using getDisplayMedia
I am using getdisplayMedia to record screen and system audio
const screenStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true, audio: true, });
this gives me the option to choose what i want to record tabs,windows or screen and along with tab and screen there is one toggle button to enable audio recording and that button is defaault on for tabs but off for screen how to keep it on for screen by default??check below images for reference
image-two
i tried adding systemAudio constraint but that did nothing --
const displayMediaOptions={ video: true, audio: true, systemAudio:"include" } screenStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
